# How to make the tokenizer to identify dates

Tags: python, spacy

I am using en_core_web_lg , I have case when the tokenizer doesn't split dates correctly:

```
self._nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")       
self._nlp.tokenizer = spacy.tokenizer.Tokenizer(self._nlp.vocab)
```

text='hi good thank you I am Chris July 6 1990'

the tokens are:

```
[('hi', 'hi', 'INTJ', 'UH', 'advmod', 'xx', True, False), 
('good', 'good', 'ADJ', 'JJ', 'ROOT', 'xxxx', True, False), 
('thank', 'thank', 'VERB', 'VBP', 'ROOT', 'xxxx', True, False), 
('you', '-PRON-', 'PRON', 'PRP', 'dobj', 'xxx', True, True), 
('I', '-PRON-', 'PRON', 'PRP', 'nsubj', 'X', True, True), 
('am', 'be', 'AUX', 'VBP', 'ROOT', 'xx', True, True), 
('Chris', 'Chris', 'PROPN', 'NNP', 'compound', 'Xxxx', True, False), 
('July', 'July', 'PROPN', 'NNP', 'attr', 'Xxxx', True, False), 
('6', '6', 'NUM', 'CD', 'nummod', 'd', False, False), 
('1982', '1990', 'NUM', 'CD', 'nummod', 'dddd', False, False)]
```

Is there a way that the tokenizer will do something like :

```
[('hi', 'hi', 'INTJ', 'UH', 'advmod', 'xx', True, False), 
('good', 'good', 'ADJ', 'JJ', 'ROOT', 'xxxx', True, False), 
('thank', 'thank', 'VERB', 'VBP', 'ROOT', 'xxxx', True, False), 
('you', '-PRON-', 'PRON', 'PRP', 'dobj', 'xxx', True, True), 
('I', '-PRON-', 'PRON', 'PRP', 'nsubj', 'X', True, True), 
('am', 'be', 'AUX', 'VBP', 'ROOT', 'xx', True, True), 
('Chris', 'Chris', 'PROPN', 'NNP', 'compound', 'Xxxx', True, False), 
('July 6 1982', 'July 6 1982', '?????', '?????', '?????', '?????', True, False)]
```

Plz ignore the ???? as I wasn't sure what the result will be.

Alternatively is there a way(without training the model) that the NER will recognize the date correctly?

Thanks,

Nir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That string is already labelled as a DATE by the NER component, even in the small model.

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

text = "hi good thank you I am Chris July 6 1990"

for ent in nlp(text).ents:
    print(ent.label_, ent, sep="\t")
```

Output:

```
PERSON  Chris
DATE    July 6 1990
```

If you want to merge entities (like dates) into single tokens [there is a pipeline function](https://spacy.io/api/pipeline-functions#merge_entities) so you can do that with one line.

Comment: Hi, the problem is that NER is not consist , for example in this case : 'I am Anna Jun 12 1993' it doesn't reorganize the date, that why I wrote without trying the NER

Comment: Oh. Well, "Anna Jun" looks like a name so that's a mistake that I could almost see a human making, and it's pretty unsurprising the model makes it... If all your strings have a date at the end maybe you should just take the last three tokens off and process them separately?

Comment: Thanks, but since it is a real life example of chats , I cant really control it, I will try the merge entities option

Comment: Maybe look at using an EntityRuler component to mark things like `Jun [one or two digit number]` as a date as a post-processing step.